# Is there a way to always stay at the searched-for Symbol location when using vscode and pressing `esc` key?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's say I use `Go to Symbol in Editor`.  Let's further say I have a function `def run():` (this is Python) that I want to jump to.

If I type `@run` in the Symbol search dropbox, the viewport will shift to `def run` in the source code.

So far, so I good.  I have found what I want!

At that point, if I press `esc` I jump back to my starting location, rather than staying at `def run()` in the source.  I have to remember to press `Enter` to get out of `Go to Symbol in Editor...` and stay at my location.

How can I make it so `esc`, by itself, always leaves me where I have found the symbol in the text?

I.e. I want to get more the behavior I get from using `Edit, Find` where `esc` leaves at the pattern location.  And pressing `Enter` when in Find mode jumps me to the next pattern hit, if any.

environment:  macos, vscode 1.63.2 (latest as of now)

p.s.  You also get the same behavior from a `Go to Line/Column...` dialog, `esc` will yank you back to your starting point, `Enter` will leave you at the new location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not currently possible.  I've tried to unbind every single keyboard shortcut bound to <kbd>Escape</kbd> key so it should basically become a dead key, yet even with this setting symbol suggest highlight were cancelled by pressing the <kbd>Escape</kbd>, so no luck.

Unbinding the primary action is normally prerequisite for changing default behaviour -- in your case for mapping it to "accept highlighted symbol" action (which I haven't found either) -- so it seems that Enter/Escape behaviour of symbol palette is not exposed for remapping.

Comment: OK, I'll leave this out for a while, but accept it if no one states otherwise.  It was worth asking this question as I tended to confuse Edit Find and Go to behavior regarding `esc` vs `Enter`.  Now I've learned to pay attention.  Might be tied to Go to's internal hardcoded response to keypresses (Enter -> stay, esc go back).